# 404 not found when I try to DELETE from my service

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, rest

I get a 404 not found when I try to DELETE from my service, on the client side I use this:

On my Service side I use this:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "DELETE", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate = "/Student")]
    void removeStudent(Student studentID);

    List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
    public void removeStudent(Student studentID)
    {
        students.Remove(students.Find(f => f.StudentID.Equals(studentID)));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what i see above, you are passing the some text to the URL on the client side BUT expecting a Student object which doesn't seem right.

I think the convention is that the DELETE should have the same URI template as a GET.

```
  [WebInvoke(Method = "DELETE", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate = "/{studentID}")]
    void removeStudent(string studentID);
```

or

```
void removeStudent(int studentID);
```

Answer (score 1):

The DELETE Http Verb is not enabled by default. Read [this](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/verbs/add) how to fix it.